# Remove CSS Attribute by Overriding CSS in Child Theme

Tags: css, child-theme

I have a theme I am trying to customize the style, and to do so, I have created a child theme. The child theme contains a `style.css` and I've been able to override certain attributes, but I can't remove them.

**Example:**

Original CSS:

```
.mvp-blog-story-img img {
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative; //I want to remove
   left: -9999px;//I want to remove
   right: -9999px;//I want to remove
   width: 100%;
   min-width: 560px;
   width: 100%;
}
```

Override CSS:

```
//This is what I want the final CSS to be
.mvp-blog-story-img img {
   margin: 0 auto;
   width: 100%;
   min-width: 0px;
 }
```

I'm assuming that this is happening because the style sheet will only override the attributes that exist in the parent theme and child theme; thus, leaving attributes that are NOT in the child theme, in the parent theme.

How can I remove the parent theme attributes within the child theme `style.css`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm assuming that this is happening because the style sheet will only
>   override the attributes that exist in the parent theme and child
>   theme; thus, leaving attributes that are NOT in the child theme, in
>   the parent theme.

That's not how it works. There's nothing special about WordPress parent theme and child theme stylesheets. They're just standard [CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS) style sheets, and they follow the same rules as any two stylesheets loaded on any other web page.

If you want to "remove" a style from one stylesheet in subsequent stylesheet, you need to provide a new value for it. If you have a `position: relative;` property, and you want to reset it to its default value you need to use [`initial`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/initial):

```
.mvp-blog-story-img img {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 100%;
    min-width: 0px;
    position: initial;
}
```

Note that `initial` doesn't work in Internet Explorer, so if IE support is required, you will need to find out what the default value is and set it to that. For `position`, that's `static`:

```
.mvp-blog-story-img img {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 100%;
    min-width: 0px;
    position: initial;
}
```

Note that if the element's position is `static` then `left` and `right` won't do anything, so you don't need to reset those.

To find the default values for properties, the [MDN web docs CSS reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Reference) is a good resource.

Comment: Thank you for helping me understand CSS a bit better! That did the tick! I appreciate the quick response.